# How does sex differentiation work in Paracerceis sculpta, the sexually tetramorphic isopod?

Tags: genetics, zoology, development, sex

[*Paracerceis sculpta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracerceis_sculpta) is a marine isopod species known for its unusual reproductive strategy:

- female: medium-sized; lives in harems run by an α male
- α male: large; keeps a harem of females
- β male: medium; mimics a female in order to enter a harem and mate
- γ male: small; mimics a juvenile in order to slip into a harem and mate

[image: P. sculpta illustration].

**How does this 4-way sex differentiation occur?** That is, what determines which of the morphs an individual develops into?

Comment: There's also the throat colors of the [side-blotched lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_side-blotched_lizard).

Answer (score 4):

> Shuster, SM & C Sassaman (1997)
>   Genetic interaction between male mating strategy and sex ratio in a marine isopod. Nature **388**: 373-377

As described in this paper, the chromosomal system of sex determination in *Paracerceis sculpta* is ZW=females, ZZ=males. Genetic evidence indicates that the morph of a ZZ male is determined by a second locus, *Ams* (*alternative mating strategy*) which exists in three allelic forms whose dominance relationship is *Ams<sup>β</sup>* > *Ams<sup>γ</sup>* > *Ams<sup>α</sup>*. So for example, to be an α type male, an individual must be ZZ *Ams<sup>α</sup>* / *Ams<sup>α</sup>*.

That's the end of the answer, what follows is supplementary information.

The paper also describes an additional layer of complexity in the sex-determining system of *P. sculpta* involving sex changes in both directions. This is explained by a model in terms of two other factors: an autosomal locus *Tfr* (*transformer*) and a cytoplasmic factor ECF (extra-chromosomal factor) which interact as shown in the Table below (taken from the paper). However, this doesn't really add anything to the *Ams* story as far as male morphs are concerned, except that some of them start as females.

[image]